# array.last and general nested array copy/access mutation confusion

Tags: swift

(XCode 6.2) Basically i have an array of arrays of instances of a class. I can without problems change the content of a inner array if i access it via `[index]` but if i first assign it to a variable the content of the inner array won`t be changed (it is first copied - obviously). When working with tree-structures/algorithms accessing by index is not very readable often. So how should i adress this following scenario the 'right' way?

Simplifed problem domain:

```
class ZNeuron {

}

class ZNet {
    var layers : [[ZNeuron]] = []
    required init() {
        self.construct()
    }
    func construct() {
        for index in 0...3 {
            self.layers.append([ZNeuron]())
            for _ in 0...4 {
                var lastInserted = self.layers.last! // 1.
                lastInserted.append(ZNeuron()) // 2.
                //self.layers.last!.append(ZNeuron()) // 3.
                //self.layers[index].append(ZNeuron()) // 4.
                println(lastInserted)
            }
        }
        println(self.layers)
    }
}

var mnet = ZNet()
```

In 1. combined with 2. i wanted to access the last inserted array and add to it. It will not add to the last inserted array but ? copy it and assing to it. 3. won't compile at all. 4. works fine though and this makes me think, there has to be some other way to access this variable/reference. I probably won't want to write that x times. In the case of 3. i guess the optinal is unwrapped to a constant by default and with the assignment to `var` i 'request' a cast to a mutable object - is this intended?

Basically i want to append an array to an array and then add objects to the last appended array without using the index all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Obj-C when you copy an array you will not copy the reference but the data stored in the array (though it will be done lazy). If you want the changed data back in the original array you need to copy the changed entries back there too.

Paste the following in Playground and you'll see:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a
a1[1] = 9
b[1] // still 2
```

**Edit:** If you really need references you have to wrap the array in a class. This way Swift will copy the reference to the object.

```
class A {
  var props = [String]()
  init(p:String) { props.append(p) }
}
var a1:[A] = [A(p: "1"), A(p: "2"), A(p: "3")]
println(a1[0].props)
var b = a1
println(b[0].props)
a1[0].props.append("two")
println(b[0].props)
```

Note: The above crashed for me in Playground but ran in a compiled source with the debugger. Swift is Alpha >:-(

Comment: Well that is what i observed. But how can i circumvent this to not always need to access the array and the object inside of it by index? Overriding array.last with the new array.last? Is that really the only option?

Comment: @Thomas Isn't there a way to copy it, like it used to be at a moment if I remember well, by reference and not by value ?

Comment: @lchamp In order to _answer myself_,  see this Q/A http://goo.gl/wtr3o9 and this test code : http://goo.gl/lHwUPO

Comment: @Alex I guess so. Swift's array handling has pros and (as you observe) cons.

Comment: @lchamp Your code refers to passing inout in a function. The OP's question is about copied arrays.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian seems to be the state. While thinking about it i can somewhat understand the rout. But i would like something, lets name iterm.. so i would not use var or let but itermim label to make clear to both reader and compiler what i try to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the syntax of Swift which comes with a load of scrap anyway >:-(